# Database strings localization in C# using .resx resource files

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, localization, resources

In our project (C# targeting .NET 4.0) translation personnel uses [ResX Resource Manager](https://resxresourcemanager.codeplex.com/) to manage localization (stored in .resx resources). This tool provides quick navigation, editing, filtering. They like a lot it's interface with side by side language columns:
[image]
Our next goal isdatabase strings localization. We have an  SQLite embedded database which stores information that is changing over time (user can perform CRUD operations via .NET application which uses ORM). Our database is already divided into two parts: language-independent part (storing GUIDs, INTs, DOUBLEs, ARRAYs etc.) and localizable part (storing GUIDs and text information). GUIDs (primary keys) in both parts are need for ORM to combine values into a single entity.

So lets assume we have localizable part **DB.TXT.en.sqlite** and the goal is to obtain for example **DB.TXT.de.sqlite** where GUIDs are still the same but text information is translated into German.

Our transtaion staff of course wants to use tool which they are familiar with (ResX Resource Manager) and doesn't wat to use any SQLite Viewing tool.

So I'm trying to implement th following approach (for example in **DB.TXT.en.sqlite** I have **Users** table with GUID Id, STRING FirstName, STRING LastName):

1. I write an utility which reads data from **DB.TXT.en.sqlite** database into .resx resource file. For example I can name properties like **Users.ee5c8268-9b1f-46f8-9327-6309b8613421.FirstName** and **Users.ee5c8268-9b1f-46f8-9327-6309b8613421.LastName**. If property already exists (string was already translated before) - do nothing  with it.
2. Translation staff work with .resx file as usual
3. I copy all data from **DB.TXT.en.sqlite** to **DB.TXT.de.sqlite**
4. I write an utility which reads .resx file, parse properties' names and create UPDATE statements to **DB.TXT.de.sqlite** (like UPDATE Users SET FirstName=Users.ee5c8268-9b1f-46f8-9327-6309b8613421.FirstName.Value WHERE Id=ee5c8268-9b1f-46f8-9327-6309b8613421).

So is this approach viable? 
Are there any drawbacks/tradeoffs in it?
Is there better/easier way to translate strings stored in database when staff doesn't work with any database viewer tool?

Comment: I always let resx translators work with excel. That also enables switching underlying tech (resx/db/json etc) easier. Everyone knows excel.

Comment: Ok, but for now  ResX Resource Manager provides reacher functionality than Excel. Nevertheless using Excel doesn't change much in described approach. So you think that using some intermediate format (.resx or .xls doesn;t matter) for translators and two utilities for reading from db/writing into it - is a good idea?

Comment: Your question in general is quite broad, not really fit for SO. Maybe [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) is better. I'm not really sure why you are talking about users, guids and an ORM when doing translations. What part of this needs an ORM? Translations should just be (culture,key) -> value. So if you want an opinion: Your solution sounds complicated, or perhaps you are not seperating your problem domains. Keep it simple, solve one problem at a time.

Comment: Your last question in the comment though; an intermediate format that you use to update a db? Why not. But you are not really motivating why you want something as complex as a DB to store your translations. Will they change frequently at runtime? is there a server involved? is there some kind of dynamic creation of strings?

Comment: DB stores information (both language-independent and localizable) and user can perform CRUD operation via .NET application which uses uses ORM. So yes - data is changing at runtime. It's serverless because we use embedded DB (SQLite). Not sure what do you mean in "dynamic creation of strings" but yes DB is growing over time of course. I will update my question and add some more info..